Enablement without undue experimentation standard
The invention is in the field of software development. In particular, it is in the consumer app space.
For the invention to be practical enough to be a consumer app on the market, it must have some level of efficiency.
Questions:

Do the specifications of the patent application need to contain the details to enable the invention with undue experimentation to the degree of it being efficient enough to be a variable consumer app on the market?
Or do the specifications just need to have enough details to enable any implementation of the invention, even if the solution is merely one with an N square time complexity?


Efficiency and practicality are not needed for patentability.
Best method is still, technically, a requirement even though it is no longer grounds for invalidation.

Efficiency and practicality are not needed to obtain a patent, but:

Or do the specifications just need to have enough details to enable any implementation of the invention, even if the solution is merely one with an N square time complexity?

Is this a solution to a problem that the person of ordinary skill would already know how to tackle?
If so, you do not need to include the solution for enablement.
If not, you must include it and it will be difficult/impossible to not limit the scope of the claim to the disclosed solution, as that would be tantamount to claiming a problem rather than a solution (means-plus-function, abstract idea, written description, scope of enablement -- there will be some way to kill it).
